# @csrf_exempt before @ajax_required or vice versa in Chrome

Tags: python, django, csrf

In Django if I put `@ajax_required` before `@csrf_exempt`, in Chrome it fails with 403 error. In Firefox both work fine. If I swap them, it works fine for Chrome. Is that normal?

Comment: `ajax_required` is not a built-in decorator in Django so a link to the source or a copy of that decorator would be helpful here.

Comment: I took it from here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/771/